# Kali Linux/Metasploit in VirtualBox - Issue with ports

Tags: network, ip, ports, metasploit, kali-linux

I've been attempting to get port 4444 to open these past couple of days. I finally figured I'd try to get it working on my Windows machine first and I finally got it. Now, no matter what I do in the Kali VM, I can't get the port to open on Kali. I'm testing it with a simple http server and canyouseeme.org and I haven't had any issues on Windows yet, but Kali just refuses to open the port. I've configured a static IP on both my windows machine and the Kali VM and I'm using the bridged adapter setting. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537751/virtualbox-port-forward-from-guest-to-host ?

Comment: What do you mean by "open the port"? On the firewall? To have a service run on that port? To access the service running on that port? We need some more info on what the problem is.

Comment: To run Metasploit on WAN.

Comment: @Purefan No, unfortunately it did not help.

Comment: What do you mean by "Kali refuses [...]"? I assume you mean to run a listener of some sort, like `ncat -lp 4444`. What do you actually do, and what does `netstat -tlnp` say?

Comment: I was simply saying that starting a basic web server on port 4444 and attempting to access it by going to my public ip:port doesn't work, meaning the port isn't open for my VM's IP. It works on windows.

Comment: Make sure it's a bridge not NAT. Change this in the VM's setting.

Comment: @k1308517 Please read the post. I said I was using bridged.

Comment: @JakeRieger if the port is blocked, you can install `ufw` (`sudo apt-get install ufw`) which is the uncomplicated firewall to open it. Then run `sudo ufw enable`, `sudo ufw allow 4444`. You might want to restart ufw too. `sudo service ufw restart`. After this, port 4444 should be opened for you. I would tell you how to do it with iptables but I'm really bad with iptables.

Comment: Seems like a network system administration question (or possibly a basic networking question) rather than an infosec question. Before playing with fancy tools, have you ever configured and tested something like a basic webserver on a VM?

Comment: I'm gonna assume you didn't intend to come off as condescending. Yes, I have. I have plenty experience with networking. May I ask the relevance? If your point was that this post should be moved to a different community  then by all means, have it moved.

Answer (score 0):

In your case,You use bridge connection in VMware which means that your windows machine ip like **192.168.1.11** then your kali Linux ip would be **192.168.1.x** you

could see your ip  address just type in terminal **ifconfig** and use namp to know how many port on your system is open.

for that Here is command: **sudo nmap yourip**

now you could see that what process running on your ip for that command: **sudo lsof -i:4444**

Now you could see what is issue with port.

Answer (score 0):

If the host that is trying to connect to your port 4444 on your Kali is on the Internet, you'll need to configure port forwarding on the router you use to access the Internet - that is, your router needs to redirect connections from 4444 coming from the Internet to your internal VM (this process varies according to the router, so just Google a guide for more information on this).

Also, if your Kali Linux VM is configured to network through a bridge, there is no need to open the port on your host system.

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Opening the port on my host machine was a troubleshooting method to make sure it wasn't my router that was the issue. I've already port forwarded port 4444 to my VM's ip and still nothing.